# How to find the diameter of an automobile inner tube

Tags: tires, measurement

I'm trying to determine the diameter of several automobile inner tubes (ranging from compact cars to semis); as in the diameter within the tube itself (possibly the "width", or even circumference of the tube).  I'm referring to the measurement on the dotted line displayed in red on the poor illustration below (the part that looks like stitching on a football).

[image: inner tube diameter]

I know it's an obscure request, but I can't seem to find a size chart or a reference to the measurement in any online guides.  Any advice on how/where I can gather this info (short of calling a bunch of vendors)?

Thank you.

Note: I'm working on an online calculator that determines cubic inches within inner tube sizes.

Comment: Are you looking to find the cubic inches of the tube when blown up inside of the tire? If not, there is no way to answer your question. Inner tubes will continue to expand as you add air.

Comment: Call the manufacturer and ask for a chart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap a tape measure around the tube. Do this enough times with different sizes, and you'll find a pattern. From that pattern, you can derive a formula.

Or try this: based on the rim size and profile of the wheel this tube goes into, you can determine the height of the tube. From that, using Pi, you can derive the circumference.